# Use commiter's name and email in Git config

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using Git on a windows development server.

It's not always the same person that makes the commits.

For now we have a default name and email defined which does not look very good in Bitbucket.

I was wondering if you could automatically use the name and email address related to the credentials used to make the commit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure which email addresses get mapped to which bitbucket accounts.

It's under "Username Aliases" under "Settings" from the repository page.

The URL is `https://bitbucket.org/<REPO_OWNER_NAME>/<REPO_NAME>/admin/committers`